# "this" is undefined when function is passed as argument in chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

*Simple example of my problem*

Consider the following situation, where I have a few functions (`a` and `b`) that I used in a promise-chain in `c`:

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor(){
        this.v1 = 1;
        this.v2 = 2;
    }

    a() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('a', this.v1);  // Do something with `this`
            resolve();
        });
    }

    b() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('b', this.v2);   // Do something with `this`
            resolve();
        });
    }

    c() {
        return this.a().then(this.b);   // passing b as argument
    }
}
```

When I call `c` and run the chain of promises, `this` is undefined in `b`.

```
const sc = new SomeClass();

sc.c().then(() =>{
    console.log('done')
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Output:

```
a 1
error [TypeError: Cannot read property 'v2' of undefined]
```

---

I know that arrow functions inherit the outer `this`, but I am not sure why it is undefined since I am invoking it from `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
this.a().then(this.b)
```

because the resulting function retrieved by `this.b` becomes unbound from `this` (you don't actually invoke it in the way stated in your question).

You can solve it in a way that is consistent with the rest of your code, by using an arrow method to preserve scope:

```
this.a().then(obj => this.b(obj))
```

or you can use `.bind` to achieve a similar result:

```
this.a().then(this.b.bind(this))
```

Comment: Which option is a more popular pattern when you have a long chain of class functions?

Comment: I'd say it's "6 of one, half a dozen of the other" choice. I'm rather fond of using arrow functions as a scope preserving mechanism and it's certainly consistent with the rest of your code.